# angular 4 typescript destructuring doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular5, destructuring

Desctruturing doesn't work when using this. syntax

```
 {this.firstName, this.lastName} = this.data;
```

this.data has value of

```
{firstName: 'joe', lastName: 'smith'}
```

but after assigning the value of this.firstName and this.lastName is still null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following to achieve destructuring without declaration:

```
({firstName: this.firstName, lastName: this.lastName} = this.data);
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

> The round braces ( ... ) around the assignment statement is required
>   syntax when using object literal destructuring assignment without a
>   declaration.

The TypeScript compiler will also complain without the wrapping parenthesis.

Here is [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20firstName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20lastName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.data%20%3D%20%7B%20firstName%3A%20'foo'%2C%20lastName%3A%20'bar'%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(%7BfirstName%3A%20this.firstName%2C%20lastName%3A%20this.lastName%7D%20%3D%20this.data)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20greet()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%60firstName%3A%20%24%7Bthis.firstName%7D%2C%20lastName%3A%20%24%7Bthis.lastName%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20greeter%20%3D%20new%20Greeter(%22world%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0D%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(greeter.greet())%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an object.

```
this.firstname= this.data.firstname;
this.lastName=this.data.lastname;
```

Comment: This isn't de-structuring, its the common way of getting data. Here requirement is specifically on de-structuring way of field population

Answer (score 0):

`({firstName:this.firstName, lastName:this.lastName} = this.data);`

[UPDATE]

You need a syntax that not only does destructuring but also assignes value:

`{propertyNameFromObject: variableValueShouldBeAssignedTo} = someObject`

Now, you just extend that not to use `variableValueShouldBeAssignedTo` but you assign it to your object property: `this.firstName`.

ref:
http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html
 (check section 10.8)

Comment: Please add some text as to how your post answers the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
{firstName : this.firstName ,lastName : this.firstName } = this.data
```

Keys Name must be similar to the the data object for Desctruturing